# Prove that for $0< k \leq 1$ and $x \geq k$, $\ln\left(\frac{1}{e-1}+x\right)-\ln\left(\frac{1}{e-1}+x-k\right) \leq \frac{k}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, inequality

I've verified that this inequality holds when graphed, but I have no idea how to prove the actual statement. I tried to use the Mean Value Theorem but that only gives me $$\ln\left(\frac{1}{e-1}+x\right)-\ln\left(\frac{1}{e-1}+x-k\right) \leq \frac{k}{x+\frac{1}{e-1}-k},$$ which is too weak of an inequality since $\frac{1}{e-1}-k$ can be less than $0$. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use $a = 1/(e-1)$ to simplify the notation a bit.

Fix $k \in (0, 1]$ and substitute $x=k+u$, then we have to show that
$$
 f(u) = \ln(a + u + k) - \ln(a + u) - \frac{k}{k+u} 
 = \ln \left( 1+\frac{k}{a+u}\right)- \frac{k}{k+u}
$$
satisfies $f(u) \le 0$ for $u \ge 0$. We have
$$
 f(0) = \ln \left( 1+\frac{k}{a}\right) - 1 \le \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{a}\right) - 1 = \ln(e) - 1 = 0
$$
and
$$
 \lim_{u \to +\infty} f(u) = 0 \, .
$$
Also
$$
 f'(u) = k \frac{(2a-k)u + ak + a^2-k^2}{(a+u+k)(a+u)(k+u)^2} \, .
$$
The factor $(2a-k)$ is positive, since $2a = 2/(e-1) > 1 \ge k$, so there are two possibilities:

- If $ak + a^2-k^2 \ge 0$ then $f'(u)\ge 0$ for all $u \ge 0$, i.e. $f$ is increasing everywhere. Because of $\lim_{u \to +\infty} f(u) = 0$ it follows that $f(u) \le 0$ for all $u \ge 0$.
- If $ak + a^2-k^2  <0$ then there is a $u^* > 0$ such that $f$ is decreasing on $[0, u^*]$ and increasing on $[u^*, \infty)$. Because of $f(0) \le 0$ and $\lim_{u \to +\infty} f(u) = 0$ it again follows that $f(u) \le 0$ for all $u \ge 0$.